# Why is my project giving me the incorrect output?

Tags: java, replit

I am learning Java, and have a "project" that I need to complete for my class.  I've created a "fortune cookie" program, that randomly selects an array index and prints out the corresponding "fortune" from an array of fortunes.  For some strange reason, in a sandbox environment my code works, but when I put it on Replit (which is where I have to submit my project from), I'm getting "Hello World!" rather than my fortune.  I'm hoping someone can take a look and let me know where it's going wrong (especially considering I don't have "Hello World!" anywhere in my code!).

This is reproduced at , which can also be seen at https://replit.com/@TacticalTaco/FortuneCookie?v=1#Main.java; the code from that project is given below.

```
import java.util.Random;

class FortuneCookie {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int upperbound = 13;
        int int_random = rand.nextInt(upperbound);
        String[] fortune_array = {
          "Never try to catch two frogs with one hand.",
          "Flowers leave their fragrance on the hand that bestows them.",
          "If you want your dinner, don’t offend the cook.",
          "Talk doesn’t cook rice.",
          "Not the fastest horse can catch a word spoken in anger.",
          "Spring is sooner recognized by plants than by men.",
          "Never has a man more need of his intelligence than when a fool asks him a question.",
          "A woman that always laughs is everybody’s wife; a man that is always laughing is an idiot.",
          "If you are planning for one year, grow rice. If you are planning for 20 years grow trees. If you are planning for centuries, grow men.",
          "He who asks is a fool for five minutes, but he who does not ask remains a fool forever.",
          "It is better to light a candle than to curse the darkness.",
          "He who opens his heart for ambition, closes it for the rest.",
          "A candle lights others and consumes itself.",
        };
        System.out.println(int_random);
        System.out.println("You're fortune is : \n" + fortune_array[int_random]);
    }
}
```

My output is

```
sh -c javac -classpath .:target/dependency/* -d . $(find . -type f -name '*.java')
 java -classpath .:target/dependency/* Main
Hello world!

```

Comment: Also, you must keep `public class Main` in a file named `Main.java`. This is a requirement for replit

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. 
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the 
[How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question. Include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to 
reproduce the issue. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also don't link to external sites, the code should be part of the question.

Comment: `sh -c` expects the argument right after the `-c` to be a complete shell command; all later arguments become arguments to that shell, starting with `$0`, then `$1` and so on. So `sh -c javac -classpath anything` runs the command `javac` with no arguments, in a shell that has defined `$0` as `-classpath`, `$1` `anything`, etc.

Comment: Mind, the fact that you're getting `Hello world!` as output implies to us that you aren't _really_ running `sh -c javac -classpath`, because if you were really running that you'd just get an error from `javac` saying it wasn't given any arguments. So you're not giving us your real command line, whereas we'd need it to reproduce the issue and test proposed fixes.

Comment: (What I expect _may_ be happening is that you aren't successfully compiling your new Main.java file -- or aren't putting its .class file in the classpath -- so you're running an old "hello world" Main.class created from a "hello world" default that replit created when you first started your project).

Comment: Found the issue.  Seems like instead of naming my class FortuneCookie, if I made it "public class Main" like @OneCricketeer mentioned, it works as intended.  My class never said anything about not being able to change that.  Do I have to change something in the .classpath or somewhere else in order to be able to name my class something else?  Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome to make a new file called `FortuneCookie.java` with `public class FortuneCookie`, but in the main file, you would have to do `FortuneCookie.main(args)`, for example... The Main file is a requirement, as mentioned

Comment: If you're going to name the class something other than Main, you need to also change the tool that starts it to no longer say it wants to start `Main`.

Comment: replit has a bunch of hidden files you can customize to change behavior; it's certainly _possible_ to customize it however you want to, but not really in reasonable scope for a comment. (Personally, I always start from scratch from a blank repl, unhide hidden files, update the Nix definition to specify what packages I want, and otherwise go from there -- but that's a more expert-centered workflow).

Comment: @aled, ...in this particular case I think it's reasonable to preserve the link as long as the code is added to the question as well -- OP turned out to have a repl.it-specific problem, and regardless, repl.it provides tools to let others quickly/easily reproduce code therein (fork a copy to one's own account, edit/run/etc therein), so it makes it easier to figure out the distance between what's already given and a proper [mre] should the issue look like it isn't reproducible at a glance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most online editors don't allow arbitrary class names. When they compile and run the code, it's going to output a `Main.class` file with `javac`, then use `java Main` (plus some other flags). When you override that, it's going to either throw an error, or output default behavior (depending on the backend system).

Also, in Java, in general, you're required to have a top-level `public class X` for any `X.java` file, even if you have nested `class` definitions within.